# Application is not working properly in iphone simulator now earlier it was working correctly

Tags: iphone, cordova, sqlite

I have an application where i used to display the data on table view on the click of the button, it was working properly and there was no issue or problem,I used to fetch the data from the sqlite3. I installed the phonegap and later I run this program, the app is running but on the click of the button it is not showing anything on the tableview, but when i run the same app in another mac, it is running correctly, I also uninstalled the phonegap and checked, but it is not working properly. What is the problem, how to overcome this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall Xcode and Re Install it.

To uninstall Xcode use `sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your Xcode and simulator. Also remove your app from the simulator and check.
This helped me in some similar situations.

Comment: I tried closing the Xcode and simulator and also removing the app from the simulator, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: So it can be problem with the xcode that you are using. Try installing an new copy of the xcode.